# Python read tuples from dictionary

Tags: python

I'm stucked with reading value from my dictionary. My dictionary is like `a = {(1,2):(1,2,3,4),(4,5,6,7),...}` and my task is to loop value, e.g.,(1,2,3,4) and read value[0] and value[1], in this case, is 1 and 2.

But when I'm not sure if there is a tuple or multiple tuples in value, how can I loop the value and read the first and second value of tuple? I mean,  if I use for loop directly towards a, then the result of loop is a value rather than a tuple. How could I deals with this situation? My only thinking is add if statement but I wonder if there is more efficient way. :)

Comment: You'll almost certainly get a comment of show us what you've done so far btw, I'd recommend edit the question with your code

Comment: Can you show us your actual dictionary, would help a lot.

Comment: From what I understand, you want to loop on values to get the keys. For that `d={} for k,v in a: d[v]=k` will invert the dictionary. Then `for el in d: if isinstance(d[el], tuple): for t in d[el]: print(t) else print(d[el])` will give you the individual values of what used to be keys in initial dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the keys in the dictionary and then pull each tuple from the dictionary and loop over those, like so:

```
for key in dict:
    for tuple in dict[key]:
        # whatever you want to do with tuple[0] and tuple[1]
```